# Как разместить экземпляр Editor Window в центр экрана?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу создать свое собственное окно и для этого создаю экземпляр класса `Editor Window` используя метод `CreateInstance` или `GetWindow`. Я хочу его разместить в центре экрана (или в центре *Unity*).

Я не нашел методы в `Unity Engine`, которые помогли бы мне сделать это. Они существуют?

Как мне сделать это через C# скрипт?

**Заметка:** `Screen.width/Screen.height` - это не то, что мне нужно, т.к. они ссылаются на игровое окно, а не на размеры самого *Unity.exe* и не на размер экрана монитора.

Answer (score 1):

```
float w = 500, h = 500;
Resolution res = Screen.currentResolution;
EditorWindow.GetWindow<T>().position=new Rect((res.width- w) *0.5f, (res.height- h)* 0.5f,w,h);
```

В центре экрана